# Align dmypy and mypy results

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to use the [mypy daemon](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mypy_daemon.html), but am finding it throwing extra errors compared with mypy.

E.g.:

```sh
$ cat t.py 
class Cat:

    other = None
$ mypy t.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
$ dmypy run -- t.py 
t.py:3: error: Need type annotation for 'other'
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is there a way to make the `dmypy` agree with `mypy`?

---

Additional info:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.5
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.800
```

Answer (score 0):

dmypy has `--local-partial-types` turned on by [default](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8046). if you add that arg to mypy, mypy will match dmypy. There is not a way, AFAIK, to make dmypy match mypy -- other than fixing the type errors that come up with `--local-partial-types`